# logic required in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a select option which works fine,but what i want is if more than one is selected then 10 % discount has to be added, how can this be done

and on selected the value multiplies in Java script

```
//javascript

function totprice(f,n,amt)
                {

                    var tot=0;
                    document.getElementById('lbl_tot'+n).value=amt*f;

                    for (var k=1; k<=document.getElementById('rowcnt').value; k++)
                    {

                            if(document.getElementById('lbl_tot'+k))
                            {
                                tot=parseInt(tot) + parseInt(document.getElementById('lbl_tot'+k).value);
                            }

                    }

                    document.getElementById('txttot').value=tot;

                    document.getElementById('txttotprice').value=tot;


                }
```

HTML

```
<select name="amt" id="amt" onchange="return totprice(this.value,2,110);">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: How do you select more than one?  It's not a multiple select

Comment: no its not multiple, on selected the value multiples with this.value * 110, but to pass a discount if selected more than one then how?

Comment: I assume OP means, that if the value of selected option `>` 1...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select tag should be

```
<select name="amt" id="amt" onchange="return totprice(this.value,2,110);" multiple>
```

To make it multi select. Now when user will select multiple options (using Shift+click) then in your JavaScript function get these values and do the processing (provide discount/ any logic)

**Updated**
You wish to multiply the value the user has selected with the discount amount (110)
In your JS have this

```
var x = parseInt(f)*parseInt(amt);
```

`If f = 2 and amt = 110 then x = 220`. You need to do `parseInt(value, radix)` by *default radix is 10*

*EXAMPLE*:

```
var optionSelected = document.getElementById('amt').value;  //optionSelected is nothing but this.value
if(optionSelected > 1)
{
 //Offer discount
 var x = parseInt(f)*parseInt(amt);  //where f and amt is passed through function call
}
else
{
 // Do nothing/ other logic
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: its not multiple. Just want discount to be passed if option value is more than one

Comment: Where do you want to pass the discount value?? do you want to pass it to another page or to another function or where?

Comment: want to pass the discount in javascript itself,if option more than one is selected else no discount